# smarty convert string to Integer/Float

Tags: smarty

I have some string value, like  `$value = "123.45";`.

Since I have to compare this `$value` with Integer, I need to convert  `$value`'s type to float.

How can I convert String to Integer/Float in smarty language?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can use php's functions floatval / intval in smarty:

```
{$value = $value|floatval}
{$value = $value|intval}
```

Multiplying by 1 would also work:

```
{$value = $value*1}
```